# How to compare passwords in a mongoose schema?

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongoose, model

How can I compare `password` and `password_confirmation`, and if they don't match then I'll print `"Passwords don't match"` to the error message?

```
const userSchema = new Schema(
  {
    username: {type: String, required: [true, "Please enter a username"], unique: [true, "Username taken"]},
    password: {type: String, required: true, minLength: [8, "Minimum password lenth is 8"]},
    password_confirmation: {type: String}
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Validating password / confirm password with Mongoose schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13982159/validating-password-confirm-password-with-mongoose-schema)

Comment: No, the answer is probably outdated. @AhmadHabib

Answer (score 1):

You can use validator in your schema.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator

```
passwordConfirm: {
type: String,
required: [true, 'Please confirm your password'],
validate: {
  // this only works on CREATE and  SAVE!!!!
  validator: function (el) {
    return el === this.password;
  },
  message: 'Password and password confirmation do not match.',
},
```

}